# Javascript - accordion doesn't start collapsed

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion, transition

With the help of [this article](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/) I created a javascript accordion.

The only problem is, that it doesn't start collapsed and I can't seem to get it that way.

Thanks for your help

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/Schlnglein/pen/vPxKdN)

```
<div id="toggle-button1" class="section akkordeon">
<div class="akkordeon-title">LOREM IPSUM TITLE</div>
<div id="akkordeon-content1" class="section collapsible">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some css to set the initial value to 0

```
#akkordeon-content1 {
  height: 0;
}
```

Also there is an HTML element called **details** who does this functionality for you.

```html
<details>
    <summary>Details</summary>
    Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>
```

> Documentation:
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

Comment: If you add "height: 0;" to #akkordeon-content the accordion keeps closing itself so this doesn't work...

Comment: You should comment this line out: `element.style.height = null;`

Comment: Like Maksims said in his comment: here is a fork https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oVZYJa

Comment: Thank you! Almost there, but now you need to click the container two times, because you first overwrite the "height: 0;" given in the css with the "height: 0;", that the javascript puts on the element, and with the second click the correct height gets added by the javascript... Any ideas how this could be fixed?

Comment: Yes, add data attribute to your html. Add data-collapse = true to the collapsed element. Check here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LaWLLo

Answer (score 1):

```
var section = document.querySelector('#akkordeon-content1');
collapseSection(section)
```

add that code to your javascript. outside of anything

Comment: Thank you this kinda works. The only thing is, that it doesn't technically start collapsed but rather collapses when you enter the page, therefore you can see the short animation uppon entering where the accordion closes. Is there maybe a way to deactivate the transition, but only for the first time?

Answer (score 1):

Just make your container hide by default.

```
.collapsible {
   height: 0;
}
```

And remove this line from code so it does not collapse back:

```
//(line 42) element.style.height = null;
```

Comment: Thank you! Almost there, but now you need to click the container two times, because you first overwrite the "height: 0;" given in the css with the "height: 0;", that the javascript puts on the element, and with the second click the correct height gets added by the javascript... Any ideas how this could be fixed?